# Underfull vbox in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, bad-box

I have an underfull vbox in the toc and I don't really know how to get rid of it. Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
  fontsize=11pt,
  twoside=true,
  BCOR=20mm,
  DIV=13,
  headsepline=true,
}
\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: It disappears if you add a section at the end of chapter 4. Don't worry about this until the document is in final-no-more-changes state as regards to the text. And badness 2547 in the TOC is not that bad.

Comment: To be precise, the complete message is `Underfull \vbox (badness 2547) has occurred while \output is active`; it means that it is emitted during the output routine, when TeX is building the page.  It is *not* an error, but only a warning: (La)TeX had to stretch a little, in the vertical direction, the lines of the table of contents, most likely in order to avoid to have the line for Chapter 5 alone at the bottom, detached from the line for Section 5.1.  You can ignore this.

Comment: the document is final, but if there is no elegant way to solve it, I guess I have to ignore it. I know its not an error, I simply don't like having too many bad boxes ;) Thanks anyways.

Comment: If the document is really final, and you don’t like that the lines of the ToC are stretched vertically that tiny bit, you can always add an empty line to the ToC, just before the line for Chapter 5.  This can be achieved, for example, by adding the command `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\null}` at the very beggining of the fifth chapter, immediately before the `\chapter` command.  But do not forget to undo this if you happen to introduce further changes in your document.

Answer (score 4):

You could just ignore the warning or you could add a bit more flexibility to the toc, for example adding

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=1em plus 3pt]{chapter}
```

to the preamble changes the stretch component of the space before the chapter entries from 1pt to 3pt which allows the toc to be set with no warnings.

(thanks to esdd for the scrbook interface to setting this)

Comment: @esdd I guess you have used scrbook before or read the manual or something: (I just used `\tracingall` and spotted a plausible skip macro in the trace:-)